# ActionBar background with MaterialComponents theme

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, material-components-android, material-components

I want to customize my ActionBar. My Theme looks as below:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@drawable/actionBarBackground</item>
</style>
```

In values folder:

```
<drawable name="actionBarBackground">#FFFFFFFF</drawable>
```

In values-night folder:

```
<drawable name="actionBarBackground">#FF000000</drawable>
```

Not sure why my ActionBar background colour doesn't change accordingly. I have tried to change my theme in different other ways as well but nothing works. Here are my other tries:

Instead of `actionBarStyle`, I used `actionBarTheme`.

```
<item name="actionBarTheme">@style/MyActionBar</item>
```

I also tried using `colorPrimary`.

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/actionBarBackground</item>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: That's probably because you've declared the colour as a drawable, which are not the same concepts.

Comment: I have also tried with colors, but still same problem.

Comment: Are you using the ActionBar or a Toolbar?

Comment: My Activity's layout file has nothing. As my theme is Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight, it includes an ActionBar by default.

Answer (score 20):

Since you are using a `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight` app theme the `ActionBar` background color is defined by default by the **`colorPrimary`** attribute.

```
  <style name="AppThemeActionBar" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/mycolor</item>
  </style>
```

where `mycolor` is define in `res/values/colors.xml`

```
<resources>
  <color name="mycolor">#xxxxxx</color>
  ...
</resources>
```

You can also customize the background color using the **`actionBarStyle`** attribute in your app theme.
Something like:

```
  <style name="AppThemeActionBar" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
      <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Custom.ActionBar</item>
      ...
  </style>
```

where:

```
  <style name="Custom.ActionBar" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="background">@color/mycolor</item>
  </style>
```

Otherwise you can use the **`actionBarTheme`** attribute to override the background color:

```
  <style name="AppThemeActionBar" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.ActionBar</item>
    ...
  </style>

  <style name="ThemeOverlay.ActionBar" parent="">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/mycolor</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

Comment: This is not clear, what's the difference between using actionBarStyle and actionBarTheme?

Comment: Thanks, your 2nd suggestion overriding `Widget.MaterialComponents.Light.ActionBar.Solid` worked for me.

Comment: @David: both are attributes but `actionBarStyle` is a style where you can customize some attributes like the background, the title text style.. while the `actionBarTheme` is a theme overlay where you can override some values defined in the app theme, like the `colorPrimary` but only for a specific widget, in this case the `ActionBar`.

Comment: Apparently, if your theme inherits from Material, `actionBarStyle` is completely ignored and the ONLY way to style the action bar is via `actionBarTheme`.  Wasted ANOTHER half day on this.

Comment: Thank for your answer, and how to change color of title and menu of actionbar, I'm using MaterialComponents

Comment: This the only advice which works for me with `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight` theme. I use `Widget.MaterialComponents.ActionBar.Primary` as parent value for my action bar.

Answer (score 16):

For me neither setting background nor colorPrimary has helped.
Apparently [this is the intended behavior](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/473), as according to [dark theme guidance](https://material.io/design/color/dark-theme.html#custom-application) for components that use a large portion of a screen. They should use colorSurface for their background instead of `colorPrimary` or `colorAccent`.  `AppBarLayouts`, `Toolbars`, and `ActionBars` now default to  their `Surface` styles in dark theme.

So I had to define colorSurface attribute for my theme in order for it to work.

```
<item name="colorSurface">@color/my_color_primary_dark</item>
```

Comment: thank you so much, you're awesome, this solution works for me, as for light primary color is picked up, but for dark, no solution was working, even with actionbarStyle or actionBarTheme,

Comment: This is a nice short way of achieving it; but please bear in mind that this also changes the colour of switches, at least when using ` parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar"`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm on the latest stable of MDC, and this is how it works here.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.ActionBar.PrimarySurface</item>
</style>
```

If you want the app bar to be the same color as your color surface, change `@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.ActionBar.PrimarySurface` to `@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.ActionBar.Surface`

Comment: Thank you, but how to change the color of title and menu of actionbar

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because that's not the right way to declare colours in an app.

Typically, colour resources are located in one-singular file: `colors.xml`

This XML file is typically located in your app's resources folder (usually `res/values/colors.xml`)

They are then declared with a `<resources>` element as the root of the XML file and your colour resources (as defined with the `<color>` element):

```xml
<!-- Note: The XML header (aka <?xml version="1.0" ...?>) is optional -->
<resources>
    <color name="your_color_res">#FFFFFF</color>
    <!-- Your other colour resources go here -->
</resources>
```

You can then specify qualifiers for your colour resources by creating the same `colors.xml` in your app's resources with the following file format:

```
res/values-<qualifier>/colors.xml
```

These colours can then be referenced with the `@color/` prefix in XML files or with `R.color.*` in your app's Java/Kotlin code.

Hope this helps!