# App Bar not following Headline 6 text appearance in dark theme (Material Design Components)

Tags: material-design, material-components-android, material-components, mdc-components

Project with MDC doesn't follow the `fontFamily` I set in Headline 6 in my theme when on dark theme.
I used metropolis_500 as my `fontFamily` in my Headline 6 style. It shows up normally on Light Theme but not on Dark Theme.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'

<!--Base Theme-->
<style name="Base.Theme.MyApp" parent="Base.Theme.MaterialThemeBuilder">
    ...
    <item name="textAppearanceHeadline6">@style/TextAppearance.MyTheme.Headline6</item>
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.Toolbar.AppBar</item>
    ...
</style>

<!--AppBar Style-->
<style name="Widget.MyTheme.Toolbar.AppBar" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Surface">
    <item name="android:background">?attr/colorAppBar</item>
    <item name="titleTextColor">?colorOnAppBar</item>
</style>

<!--Headline 6-->
    <style name="TextAppearance.MyTheme.Headline6" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline6">
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/metropolis_500</item>
</style>
```

I tried explicitly specifying the use of Headline 6 in my AppBar Style and did not work.

```
<!--AppBar Style-->
<style name="Widget.MyTheme.Toolbar.AppBar" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Surface">
    <item name="android:background">?attr/colorAppBar</item>
    <item name="titleTextColor">?colorOnAppBar</item>
    <item name="titleTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.MyTheme.Headline6</item>
</style>
```

I also tried explicitly specifying the `toolbarStyle` on Dark Theme Style.

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Base.Theme.MyApp">
    ...
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.Toolbar.AppBar</item>
</style>
```

I also tried reverting to the default Material Components toolbarStyle.

```
<item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Surface</item>
```

[image: What the text appearance of the toolbar supposed to be]

[image: What instead looked like in Dark Theme]

Nothing worked. Light theme is alright, but dark theme isn't. The metropolis font shows up properly on other parts in dark theme like in `TextViews` that use the Headline 6 style.

Comment: I have run into this same issue. I noticed colorPrimary value isn't applied to the app bar background (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58363200/actionbar-background-with-materialcomponents-theme). Perhaps this is related.

Comment: @EricWilliams, I just posted a possible solution to your problem. Hope it helps. Cheers.