# Android actionbar customization does not change color

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-styles

I am trying to customize the action bar in my android application. The following is in my `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="backgroundColor">#000000</item>
</style>
```

And I have

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
```

in my `AndroidManifest.xml`.

My expectation is that this should turn the action bar black. However, this does not happen, the action bar stays white. I would be very happy for any pointers to why my expectation does not match reality. I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: try `<item name="android:background">#000000</item>` insteade of `backgroundColor`

Comment: I tried this, and the action bar is still white.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using an `ActionBar` you can use the **`actionBarStyle`** attribute in your app theme:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
      <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
 </style>

  <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
       <item name="background">#000000</item>
  </style>
```

You can also use the **`actionBarTheme`** attribute:

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
     <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.ActionBar</item>
  </style>


  <style name="ThemeOverlay.ActionBar" parent="">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#000000</item>
  </style>
```

Comment: The `actionBarTheme` worked wonders. However, I can still not get `actionBarStyle` to work. If I copy your first block of code, the compiler complains that the item named background should not take a raw string as an argument, and in my original block of code, the action bar turns out white. Any ideas to why this might be?

Comment: @bvdhen Try to use a reference like `@color/black`. Are you using a `Toolbar` in your layout?

Comment: For those who are using MDC, https://stackoverflow.com/a/58368668