# remove toolbar in fragment

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I used Androids "Bottom Navigation Activity"-example but in every fragment, I have a blank toolbar at the top of the fragment (white bar at the top of the screen in screenshot). I already applied NoActionBar in the Manifest file and also in the layout preview, I can't see a Toolbar. How can I remove the toolbar at the top of each fragment?

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="de.myapp.test">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Quizeule">
    <activity android:name=".activities.PlayActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".activities.SplashScreenActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activities.LoginActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Themes.xml:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.Quizeule" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
</resources>
```

[image]

Comment: add these <item name="windowActionBar">false</item> <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item> in your theme. let me know if this work ill post as answer,

Comment: you need to set the theme for the activity in the manifest for a specific activity.

Comment: @ahmadbajwa unfortunately that did not work, it doesnt change anything

Comment: @rm-rf while using that lines use this parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"

Comment: Can you post one fragment and its parent XML layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `activity_main.xml` remove `android:paddingTop="?actionBarSize"` and that will fix the error

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

İf you use java ; write in fragment onCreate:

```
 GetActivity.getSupportedActionBar.hide();
```

Or ,

```
    // set Windows Flags to Full Screen
 getWindow().setFlags( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Or if you use kotlin ; write in onCreateview:

```
(activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar!!.hide()}
```

Or

```
 requiredActivity.supportActionBar!!.hide()
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try adding below in Theme.Quizeule ?

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. Nothing changed

Comment: The 2 provided lines are also already in this themes parent

Answer (score 1):

This is a default behavior for `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar` Material design dark Theme. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58363200/actionbar-background-with-materialcomponents-theme#answer-60825939) for more info

If you still want to use this DayNight theme, then you have to remove `item name="colorPrimary"` attribute and use `item name="colorSurface"` instead.

Or you can use `Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar` theme if you don't need Dark mode effect.

Comment: I tried both solutions and read the linked post but it just changed the color of my app but the blank toolbar was still there the whole time

Comment: @rm-rf  sorry to hear that.. is it still shown with `Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add these `windowActionBar` and `windowNoTitle`

```
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
   </style>
```

Comment: That did not work as well, nothing changed expect for the colors of my buttons, but they toolbar is still there

Comment: Try to add this theme in specific activity like this, <activity
            android:name=".activities "
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Quizeule" />

Comment: did not work as well, should I  add any other code? Could there be a other problem?

Comment: Add this separate theme <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style> for no toolbar